# pagerAdapter reference a programmed layout android

Tags: android

I'm usually use pager adapter to scroll through different layouts, but this time my layouts were created with java code instead of xml. Normally when choosing the resource id I reference R.layout.file. Having created the layout with java code, I'm not aware how to reference the resource. Does anyone know how to do this?

Sample code of a layout I created that I want to reference:

```
LinearLayout ParentLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
ParentLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
ParentLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

Normally for a pager adapter I have something like this:

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}

public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

     int resId = 0;
     switch (position) {
     case 0:
         resId = R.layout.xmlfile1; //I want to reference the ParentLayout I created above
         break;
     case 1:
         resId = R.layout.xmlfile2;
         break;
     case 2:
         resId = R.layout.xmlfile2; 
         break;

}
     View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
     ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
     return view;
}

...

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

 int resId = 0;
 View view = null;
 switch (position) {
 case 0:
     view = createView(); // the layout you create above
     break;
 case 1:
     resId = R.layout.xmlfile2;
     view = inflater.inflate( resId, null );
     break;
 case 2:
     resId = R.layout.xmlfile2; 
     view = inflater.inflate( resId, null )
     break;

 }
 ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
 return view;
}

View createView(){
     // create your layout right here.
}
```

Comment: did you mean to use inflate.createView()? What do I reference for the variables of CreateView? It asks for a string but I'm not sure what string they are referring to. I have a separate class that can instantiate objects with layouts. I would like to have that layout showing on the CreateView. I hope this helps explain what I'm trying to do

Comment: I have edited my answer. Not sure that answers your question. Basically, you create your layout inside `createView()`.